# Why do individual shards in MongoDB report more delete operations compared to corresponding mongos in a sharded cluster?

Tags: mongodb

So I have a production sharded MongoDB cluster that has 8 shards (replica sets) managed by mongos. Let's say I have 20 servers which are running my application and each of the servers runs a mongos process that manages the 8 shards.

Given this setup, when I check the number of ops on each of my mongos on the 20 servers, I can see that my number of inserts and deletes are in proportion - which is in accordance with my application logic. However, when I run `mongostat --discover` on the individual shards, I see that deletes are nearly 4x the number of inserts which violates both my application logic as well as the 1:1 ratio indicated by mongos. Straightforward intuition supports that mongos would write to only one shard and so the average ratio of inserts and deletes across individual shards should be the same as that on mongos (which the application directly writes to) unless mongos does something different internally with the shards.

Could anyone point me to any relevant info on why this would happen or let me know if something could possibly wrong with my infra?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that I was running the `remove()` queries to mongos without specifying my shard key. In that case, mongos does not know which shard to direct the query to and thus broadcasts the query to all the shards effectively performing more deletes than a targeted query.

Check [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/) for more information.

Comment: Not too sure, but I think chunk migrations are also counted in those stats, which would be a smart way of identifying problems with the shard key...